# MongoDb/GridFs (C# driver) : WiredTiger caching problem/questions

Tags: mongodb, gridfs, wiredtiger

I've been doing tests with GridFs (C# driver) recently and came across a problem where after uploading some ~100k files weighting aprox 1.5mb each (some are 50mb+ and some are ~200kb) : Mongodb server's memory consumption rised up to ~6.5Gb with ~6Gb for wired tiger caching only (db.serverstatus().wiredTiger.cache.bytes currently in the cache). Another problem is that, after deleting every documents from fs.files and fs.chunks and restarting the server, wired tiger cache is still ~6Gb which leads the process to stick to 6.5Gb RAM.

My question are :

- Is this kind of cache size usual for this number of file ?
- How/when does wired tiger empty/evict it's cache ?
- Is there some way to tune it without impacting performances ?

Specs : MongoDb server 4.2 (no storage.wiredTiger.engineConfig.cacheSizeGB configured) , C#/GridFs driver 2.9, Windows 10 (16Gb RAM)

Thanks a lot !

```
"cache" : {
        "application threads page read from disk to cache count" : 11456,
        "application threads page read from disk to cache time (usecs)" : 3922601,
        "application threads page write from cache to disk count" : 49,
        "application threads page write from cache to disk time (usecs)" : 6539,
        "bytes belonging to page images in the cache" : 6314172728.0,
        "bytes belonging to the cache overflow table in the cache" : 182,
        "bytes currently in the cache" : 6315679556.0,
        "bytes dirty in the cache cumulative" : 475772,
        "bytes not belonging to page images in the cache" : 1506827,
        "bytes read into cache" : 9863425672.0,
        "bytes written from cache" : 399800,
        "cache overflow cursor application thread wait time (usecs)" : 0,
        "cache overflow cursor internal thread wait time (usecs)" : 0,
        "cache overflow score" : 0,
        "cache overflow table entries" : 0,
        "cache overflow table insert calls" : 0,
        "cache overflow table max on-disk size" : 0,
        "cache overflow table on-disk size" : 0,
        "cache overflow table remove calls" : 0,
        "checkpoint blocked page eviction" : 0,
        "eviction calls to get a page" : 5335,
        "eviction calls to get a page found queue empty" : 56,
        "eviction calls to get a page found queue empty after locking" : 105,
        "eviction currently operating in aggressive mode" : 0,
        "eviction empty score" : 0,
        "eviction passes of a file" : 112,
        "eviction server candidate queue empty when topping up" : 25,
        "eviction server candidate queue not empty when topping up" : 87,
        "eviction server evicting pages" : 0,
        "eviction server slept, because we did not make progress with eviction" : 468,
        "eviction server unable to reach eviction goal" : 0,
        "eviction server waiting for a leaf page" : 25876,
        "eviction state" : 128,
        "eviction walk target pages histogram - 0-9" : 0,
        "eviction walk target pages histogram - 10-31" : 0,
        "eviction walk target pages histogram - 128 and higher" : 0,
        "eviction walk target pages histogram - 32-63" : 0,
        "eviction walk target pages histogram - 64-128" : 112,
        "eviction walk target strategy both clean and dirty pages" : 0,
        "eviction walk target strategy only clean pages" : 112,
        "eviction walk target strategy only dirty pages" : 0,
        "eviction walks abandoned" : 6,
        "eviction walks gave up because they restarted their walk twice" : 0,
        "eviction walks gave up because they saw too many pages and found no candidates" : 0,
        "eviction walks gave up because they saw too many pages and found too few candidates" : 0,
        "eviction walks reached end of tree" : 6,
        "eviction walks started from root of tree" : 6,
        "eviction walks started from saved location in tree" : 106,
        "eviction worker thread active" : 4,
        "eviction worker thread created" : 0,
        "eviction worker thread evicting pages" : 5177,
        "eviction worker thread removed" : 0,
        "eviction worker thread stable number" : 0,
        "files with active eviction walks" : 0,
        "files with new eviction walks started" : 6,
        "force re-tuning of eviction workers once in a while" : 0,
        "forced eviction - pages evicted that were clean count" : 0,
        "forced eviction - pages evicted that were clean time (usecs)" : 0,
        "forced eviction - pages evicted that were dirty count" : 0,
        "forced eviction - pages evicted that were dirty time (usecs)" : 0,
        "forced eviction - pages selected because of too many deleted items count" : 0,
        "forced eviction - pages selected count" : 0,
        "forced eviction - pages selected unable to be evicted count" : 0,
        "forced eviction - pages selected unable to be evicted time" : 0,
        "hazard pointer blocked page eviction" : 0,
        "hazard pointer check calls" : 5173,
        "hazard pointer check entries walked" : 27762,
        "hazard pointer maximum array length" : 3,
        "in-memory page passed criteria to be split" : 0,
        "in-memory page splits" : 0,
        "internal pages evicted" : 0,
        "internal pages queued for eviction" : 0,
        "internal pages seen by eviction walk" : 246,
        "internal pages seen by eviction walk that are already queued" : 0,
        "internal pages split during eviction" : 0,
        "leaf pages split during eviction" : 0,
        "maximum bytes configured" : 7990149120.0,
        "maximum page size at eviction" : 0,
        "modified pages evicted" : 0,
        "modified pages evicted by application threads" : 0,
        "operations timed out waiting for space in cache" : 0,
        "overflow pages read into cache" : 0,
        "page split during eviction deepened the tree" : 0,
        "page written requiring cache overflow records" : 0,
        "pages currently held in the cache" : 6306,
        "pages evicted by application threads" : 2,
        "pages queued for eviction" : 11200,
        "pages queued for eviction post lru sorting" : 10953,
        "pages queued for urgent eviction" : 704,
        "pages queued for urgent eviction during walk" : 0,
        "pages read into cache" : 11478,
        "pages read into cache after truncate" : 2,
        "pages read into cache after truncate in prepare state" : 0,
        "pages read into cache requiring cache overflow entries" : 0,
        "pages read into cache requiring cache overflow for checkpoint" : 0,
        "pages read into cache skipping older cache overflow entries" : 0,
        "pages read into cache with skipped cache overflow entries needed later" : 0,
        "pages read into cache with skipped cache overflow entries needed later by checkpoint" : 0,
        "pages requested from the cache" : 14583,
        "pages seen by eviction walk" : 13301,
        "pages seen by eviction walk that are already queued" : 1855,
        "pages selected for eviction unable to be evicted" : 4,
        "pages selected for eviction unable to be evicted as the parent page has overflow items" : 0,
        "pages selected for eviction unable to be evicted because of active children on an internal page" : 4,
        "pages selected for eviction unable to be evicted because of failure in reconciliation" : 0,
        "pages selected for eviction unable to be evicted due to newer modifications on a clean page" : 0,
        "pages walked for eviction" : 24882,
        "pages written from cache" : 52,
        "pages written requiring in-memory restoration" : 0,
        "percentage overhead" : 8,
        "tracked bytes belonging to internal pages in the cache" : 1000672,
        "tracked bytes belonging to leaf pages in the cache" : 6314678884.0,
        "tracked dirty bytes in the cache" : 120312,
        "tracked dirty pages in the cache" : 7,
        "unmodified pages evicted" : 5175
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

The database will use memory available on the machine.

Your stats show less than half memory used by mongodb, which reflects MongoDB documentation.

There are various knobs available for wired tiger cache size.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it normal that cache data is kept even after documents have been deleted ?

Comment: Depends on what is cached exactly, if you did not compact the database the space is still allocated for the data you had.

Comment: On a production machine, would you suggest setting wired tiger cache size above default (say 80% of total RAM) ?

Comment: Depends on the machine in question, workload etc. You want the database to use available memory.

Comment: Ok, I say that because mongodb official documentation says "Avoid increasing the WiredTiger internal cache size above its default value", default value being 50% of (RAM - 1 GB)

Comment: Updated the answer to be aligned with documentation.